# Deleted SMSs do not sync between Mac and iPhone

Tags: iphone, mac, messages, data-synchronization, messages-in-icloud

I have configured Messages app on my Mac. Any SMS that I receive on iPhone is synced on my Mac. If read the SMS from iPhone it is marked as read on Mac and vice-versa.

But if I delete any SMS from iPhone, it does not get deleted from Messages app on Mac. The same issue is other way round.

What is the issue here and how can I resolve it?

Update 1:

This is how my preferences are set.

[image]

￼

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, finally got it to work. The documentation for [Use Messages in iCloud](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT208532) mentions below (emphasis mine).

> To turn on Messages in iCloud, make sure that you've set up iCloud and
> are signed in with the same Apple ID on all your devices. You also
> need to *use two-factor authentication with your Apple ID*, and *turn on
> iCloud Keychain*.

I already had two-factor authentication turned on. I turned on iCloud Keychain and the deleted messages start disappearing everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue with macOS 11.0 and I am not sure if it happened because of Big Sur using the new Messages app. What resolved this was to go to my Preferences > iMessage tab and select the Enable Messages in iCloud option by checking the checkbox. Then, click the button that says sync now and they will sync.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I tried this option but didn't work work me. I have updated my question with screenshot for preferences.